# AWS RDS MySQL is it safe to change binary logging settings

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, binary-log

I need to change few settings in RDS MySQL parameter group. I was wondering if it's safe to perform these changes or should I take a preventive approach ?

Here's the parameters I need to change:

- binlog_checksum = none
- binlog_row_image = full
- binlog_format = row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it should be safe. These are typical steps to enable replication with a external DB or a cross region replica. There are some articles from AWS like [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/enable-binary-logging-aurora/) that goes about that. I read several in the past and never found any specific warning, other than the fact that [crash recovery can take longer once binary logs are enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.StorageReliability.html#Aurora.Overview.CrashRecovery). But in general it shouldn't be a concern because it doesn't affect the capacity of recovery so you won't see yourself in any real trouble.

Regarding `binlog_checksum` this will disable logging the checksum of events, which in general won't cause any problem, but in case your binary logs are enabled -not sure if this is the first time you enable it or you are just doing changes- you may want to think if you are using that for anything at all. If nothing comes to your mind, most probably you are not using it.

Comment: Can binary logging cause extra charges? If yes, then will you please Edit your Answer with a little use case. Thank you.